# Select data from another table if exists, if not display null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

**Invoices**

```
ID | Amount
-----------
1  | 123.54
2  | 553.46
3  | 431.34
4  | 321.31
5  | 983.12
```

**Credit Memos**

```
ID | invoice_ID | Amount
------------------------
1  | 3          | 25.50
2  | 95         | 65.69
3  | 51         | 42.50
```

I want to get a result set like this out of those two tables

```
ID | Amount | Cr_memo
---------------------
1  | 123.54 |
2  | 553.46 |
3  | 431.34 | 25.50
4  | 321.31 |
5  | 983.12 |
```

I've been messing with joins and whatnot all morning with no real luck.

Here is the last query I tried, which pulled everything from the Credit Memo table...

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Amount FROM Invoices AS A
LEFT JOIN Credit_Memos AS B ON A.ID = B.invoice_ID
```

Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Query looks fine add `B.Cr_memo` in select

Comment: Your query works (if you add the column from the second table): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b2a53/2/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query would work fine. Just add `Credit_memo.Amount` with an alias:

```
SELECT Inv.ID,Inv.Amount,IFNULL(C.Amount,'') AS Cr_memo
FROM Invoices Inv LEFT JOIN
    Credit_Memos C ON Inv.ID=C.invoice_ID
```

Result:

```
ID  AMOUNT  CR_MEMO
1   124 
2   553 
3   431     25.50
4   321 
5   983
```

See result in [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4524a).

Comment: Ha, thank you. That worked perfect. I totally forgot about IFNULL.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got the answer `Left Outer Join` is what you need but you missed to select `Cr_memo` from `Credit_Memos` table. Since you don't want to show Null values when there is no `Invoices_ID` in `Credit Memos` table use `IFNULL` to make `NULL's` as Empty string

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Amount, IFNULL(B.Cr_memo,'') AS Cr_memo
FROM Invoices AS A
LEFT JOIN Credit_Memos AS B 
ON A.ID = B.invoice_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.

```
  SELECT A.ID, A.Amount, IFNULL(B.amount,0) AS Cr_memo  FROM Invoices AS A
  LEFT JOIN Credit_Memos AS B ON A.ID = B.invoice_ID
```

here is  some useful link about  left join [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) and [another](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-left-joins.htm)